# Android app having a marketplace within the app

Tags: android, marketplace, android-pay

I've been going through a design for an app I wish to be making soon. My app will rely on user generated content. Is it possible to have users add an item to this in-app marketplace and recieve payments when other users buy from them directly using Google Wallet or PayPal? Is there a recommended way of implementing this type of feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any recommended way to do this, however, doing this your app will likely not be allowed to be uploaded to the Google Play Store.

This would be against Google's Terms of Service as a developers apps is not allowed to make money through other means and other purchases that are made within the app have to go via the Google Play.